# making Microsoft visual studio code debug console clean

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

How can I really make my Microsoft visual studio code console clean so that no path shows while I run my code. I only want to see my output and nothing more than that. please give me suggestion if you have any idea.[click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo6L3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Automatically close the Console Window when Debugging stops.

---

To do this, first go to `tools`->`options`->`debugging`->`Automatically close the Console Window when Debugging stops`

And then click `debug`->`start without debugging`->

2. Or Use System Pause command

---

Type this at the end of your program:-
`system('pause')`

**Warning** : This will only work on windows.

And then click `debug`->`start debugging`